# Can't boot from USB with new hard drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup

I have a MacBook Pro A1278 Mid-2009 13" Core 2 Duo 2.53 and the hard drive is going out. When I put a new HDD in (or no HDD) it will not boot from USB (or CD). When I put the old failing hard drive back in, then it WILL recognize a bootable USB drive. But that does not help me because I am trying to install the OS on a new drive. When I hold down the "option" key at startup, it goes to white screen, plays the chime music, then an arrow appears, then nothing happens no matter how long you hold it. With the bad drive it will quickly show both the HDD and the USB as options. I tried to format the new HDD to Mac file system and it still will not boot from USB unless I have the old bad drive installed. What could be causing this?

**I have an update** I made a big mistake. I found out the MacBook is not recognizing my recovery USB drive when the original hard is installed. What I was seeing was the recovery partition of the bad hard drive, which happen to have the same name. So the real problem is that the MacBook cannot boot **any** USB drive or CD at all. I guess I should delete this post since the problem is so different?

Comment: What OS are you trying to install? Those old Macs are not good at booting ISB unless it’s  macOS

Comment: El Capitan. The Apple website said that was the newest OS that would work with this model. I know it works because as I was saying, it will boot off the USB just fine and start the El Capitan installer if the bad hard drive is installed